# What is a 'global' phone? (ex: Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge model SM-G935F)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge, roaming

Is the 'global' model of a phone the same thing as an 'international version?'
I'm shopping for an S7 edge, and I've heard all over the internet that the international version doesn't work with Samsung Pay.
Also, this may be a dumb question, would a model such as the SM-G935FD (a Taiwan model) be considered an 'international version?'

Is the distinction thus:
--US--
SM-G9350
SM-G935A (AT&T, Cricket USA)
SM-G935P (Sprint, Boost, Virgin USA)
SM-G935R (US Cellular)
SM-G935T (T-Mobile, Metro PCS USA)
SM-G935V (Verizon USA)
--International--
SM-G935F (Global)
SC-02H (Japan Docomo)
SCV33 (Japan au)
SGH-N611 (Japan Docomo)
SM-G935D (Japan Docomo)
SM-G935FD (Taiwan)
SM-G935J (Japan au)
SM-G935K (Korea)
SM-G935L (Korea)
SM-G935S (Korea)
SM-G935W (Canada)

[I got this list from http://willmyphonework.net - I use this site as I'm phone shopping to check whether a certain model will work with my carrier]  (this example is to help me further understand, you see. Edit/shorten as you see fit.)

Comment: For Samsung devices, suffixes F/FD are *always* considered "international" no matter how broad the region they're actually sold in. FD is also increasingly wide-spread, as the market starts to see some of these in Europe too.

Comment: As for Pay, I assume that probably Pay has not rolled out for the region the F/FD variants are sold in. Once it is, you should be able to flash the latest firmware from that region, and gain Pay capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I chatted with a Samsung representative, and they informed me that their global model phones are indeed considered international. In re-reading my question now, I realize my question may not have been as clear as it could have been- I'm in the market for a new S7 Edge, and so was curious about what it meant when one of *Samsung's* phone models was "global," such as the SM-G935F.

So, the rep said the global model, and any non-US models (Japan Docomo, Taiwan, Japan au, Korea, Canada, etc) are considered international. He also confirmed that they do not currently work on Samsung Pay, and he does not know when this will happen, if it does.

So this is correct:
**--US--**
SM-G935A (AT&T, Cricket USA)
SM-G935P (Sprint, Boost, Virgin USA)
SM-G935R (US Cellular)
SM-G935T (T-Mobile, Metro PCS USA)
SM-G935V (Verizon USA)
**--International--**
SM-G935F (Global)
SM-G9350 (China) [credit: Andy Yan]
SC-02H (Japan Docomo)
SCV33 (Japan au)
SGH-N611 (Japan Docomo)
SM-G935D (Japan Docomo)
SM-G935FD (Taiwan)
SM-G935J (Japan au)
SM-G935K (Korea)
SM-G935L (Korea)
SM-G935S (Korea)
SM-G935W (Canada)

Comment: I believe that G9350 is not sold in the US - it's a dual-SIM exclusive for China (mainland, HK) and probably other APAC countries.

Answer (score 0):

As for the 1st question, CDMA(Verizon and Sprint) is often referred to as Global.

For the 2nd, for Samsung Devices I'm pretty sure all international variants are the ones with Exynos CPUs instead of Qualcomm ones. So yes, the Taiwanese phone would be international.