# Samsung Tab A7 Lite Model Number Suffix Meaning

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-tab, sim-unlocking

What do the suffix numbers on Samsung Tablets (and possibly phones) mean.

I ask because I work at a prepaid cell phone retailer. We carry the Galaxy Tab A7 Lite. The model number is SM-T227U.

I had seen something on a forum on a page about a cell phone model where it was said that the "U" stands for unrootable.

When I search for details about rooting the T227U I get pages talking about the "T227" saying it is indeed rootable.

Does the U stand for unrootable? Is the T227U rootable?

What exactly do the suffix letters on a Samsung tablet indicate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a 'global' phone? (ex: Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge model SM-G935F)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/179873/what-is-a-global-phone-ex-samsung-galaxy-s7-edge-model-sm-g935f)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check which CPU chipset do I have?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/150397/how-can-i-check-which-cpu-chipset-do-i-have)

Comment: @alecxs partially.. the second one seems to imply that the U means unlocked. Which seems unlikely because none of our devices are supposed to be unlocked. But I'm about to buy it just to see. Those lists are very helpful though. Thank you

Comment: I think "unlocked" in this context means "not carrier locked/branded".

Comment: Yes... That is exactly what unlocked means in this context. The question is, whether or not the U stands for unlocked. Once I have a little more time to work with the tablet I'll post an answer with what I can find on the subject